# How to configure, in a Jenkinsfile, the database to be used by the test suite of a Rails app in Jenkins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins

I have a Rails app which uses a PostgreSQL database, and I want to run the test suite in Jenkins. I started looking for the configuration of a Jenkinsfile to execute the test suite, and kind of understand the usage of agents to execute the Rails app inside a container. But I haven't found any reference regarding how to configure a database to be used by the tests.

Do I have to configure the database in my Jenkinsfile?

If so, how do I do it? The DB will be another agent?

If so, how to configure a second agent (all the examples I've found have only one agent)?

Comment: Jenkins has no configuration for _which database_ to use for the test suite, you can specify that on `database.yml` file and make sure that you have Postgres SQL installed on Jenkins server and the username, password is added on the `database.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the database in a rails app via [`database.yml` or `ENV['DATABASE_URL']`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database).`ENV['DATABASE_URL']` is actually merged with `database.yml` but the env var takes precedence.

You can [set ENV vars in your Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables) though environment:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        DATABASE_URL= 'postgresql://localhost/my_test_database?pool=5'
    }
    # ...
}
```

You may want to [use credentials](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/#configuring-credentials) through instead of hard-coding your db username/password into your Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        DATABASE_URL= credentials('jenkins-database-url')
    }
    # ...
}
```

If you want to split this into multiple configuration options your can either use interpolation in your Jenkinsfile or use ERB in your `database.yml`